# Injecting Alasql in AngularJS: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, controller, alasql

I am trying to inject alasql so that I can export a table into xlsx sheet. I found AlaSQL as a solution and refered [http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/00nfeq12/][1] . This is the easy solution to my project. But on injecting

```
//controller.js
    var App = angular.module("application", [ 'ngRoute','ngCookies','alasql']);
```

I get an error:

> angular.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Application&p1=Erro…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5436%2FIAt_cloud%2Fjs%2Fshared%2Fangular.js%3A19%3A463)

I have included all the js files in the main Home page.

```
  //Home.html
<script src="js/shared/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/shared/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/shared/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/user/controller.js"></script>
```

Can alasql be used in controller in any other way? Help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject it like that.
Simply add both the alasql.min.js and xlsx.core.min.js to your html as you have.

However I the correct path for the alaqsl one is /dist/alasql.min.js not console/alasql.min.js. That one is only applicable to the xlsx.core.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Angular.js

> Please include the file normally and not via requireJS

So please include it without `alasql` in `angular.module(...` and use the CDN for AlaSQL to make sure the path does not change:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```